# Hololens Emulator Settings Discarded after restart via Visual Studio

Tags: hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

If change settings inside the **Hyper-V-Manager** (for Example choose a external Virtual Network Switch for the Emulator NAT Adapter as described in this Blog Article "Connecting The HoloLens Emulator To the Internet": http://hololenshelpwebsite.com/Blog/EntryId/1008/Connecting-The-HoloLens-Emulator-To-the-Internet), these settings are only taken till the next Start via Visual Studio Debug "Hololens EMulator...". After this all settings are restored to the default.

This is very annoying, because so i must change the configuration after every start.

I hope anybody knows a solution for this problem.